# scope function is giving not defined error in angular jasmine testing

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am calling a function **$scope.getManagerDetails()** in my child controller.when I am running my test file for child controller I am getting **$scope.getManagerDetails is not a function** error.Here ManagerController is parent controller and the other one is child controller.Please help.Thanks in advance

1)Manager Controller

```
 (function(angular){
    'use strict'
    angular.module('APP').controller('managerCtrl',managerController);
    managerController.$inject=['$scope'];
    function managerController($scope){
        $scope.getManagerDetails = function(){
            //some logic
        }
    }
})(window.angular)
```

2)Employee Controller

```
    (function(angular){
    'use strict'
    angular.module('APP').controller('employeeCtrl',employeeController);
    employeeController.$inject=['$scope'];
    function employeeController($scope){
        console.log($scope.getManagerDetails())
    }
})(window.angular)
```

3)Test for employee controller

```
describe('Employee Controller',function(){

    var $scope,
        $rootScope,
        $injector,
        $controller,
        employeeController;

    beforeEach(module('APP'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_,_$injector_,_$controller_){
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $injector = _$injector_;
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        employeeController = $controller('employeeCtrl',{
            $scope:$scope
        });
    }));

    it('should have controller be defined',function(){
        expect(employeeController).toBeDefined();
    })

})
```

Comment: can you please add your html code of both the controllers

Comment: when you are running your application , is console.log($scope.getManagerDetails()) this statement working fine without any error

Comment: how do you expect that `managerCtrl` controller function should get called from `employeeCtrl` controller? does `employeeCtrl` is child of `managerCtrl` on view?

Comment: when I am running the application console.log($scope.getManagerDetails()) is working fine.Html is some thing like  
<div ng-controller="managerCtrl">
     <div ng-controller="employeeCtrl">
      
     </div>
   </div>

Comment: Yes as I mentioned managerCtrl is parent one while employeeCtrl is the child controller @PankajParkar

Comment: @Nitya answer added by rob is the thing you need to look at..

Comment: That was what I was looking for @PankajParkar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getManagerDetails()` is not defined in Employee Controller (it's defined in Manager Controller) so you probably want to mock the function along with any other dependencies Employee Controller has. e.g.

```
$scope = $rootScope.$new();
$scope.getManagerDetails = angular.noop;
```

That being said, nesting controllers like this and relying on scope inheritance is not a best practice. It would be better to create a directive with an isolated scope to encapsulate everything in Employee Controller and the associated HTML.

Comment: Thank you.This is what I was looking for.what does angular.noop do?does it represent a function without having any functionality?

Comment: it's just a function that doesn't do anytihng. e.g. it's the same as `function() {}`

Comment: @Nitya `noop` stands for no operation, behind the scene it is `function(){ }` blank function, but while looking at code it adds more readability by having `angular.noop`.. Already did +1